# Bootstrap Carousel Prev/Next malfunctioning in Angular-seed app

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-carousel, angular-seed

I have added Bootstrap in Angular-Seed project. The carousel-indicators are working fine but there is problem with the Prev/Next button.

On clicking Prev button, it switches to Last image & stays on it even if you click prev again. On clicking Next button, it switches to 2nd image & stays on it.

Tried replacing JQuery/Bootstrap with the CDN links but their versions is not the issue.

Here is the carousel I'm using:-

```
    <div class="container">
      <div id="carouselControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselControls" data-slide-to="0" class="active"</li>
        <li data-target="#carouselControls" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselControls" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselControls" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselControls" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="Main.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="mainOne.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="numberFive.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="numberFour.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="numberThree.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data- 
   slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"> 
    </span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>

        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carouselControls" role="button" 
    data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"> 
    </span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```